# Isn't 2 a vacuously prime number?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics

Since there are no numbers between two and one 1, 2, two cannot be divisible by a number other than itself and one.
This is an instance of what mathematicians call [vacuous truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth), where something is true simply because no potential counterexample can exist. They still consider such statements as true.
but since a vacuously true truth is vacuously true.
doesn't it make 2 a vacuously prime number?

Comment: There are no "vacuously prime numbers".

Comment: For an "alternative" def, you can see Euclid's [Elements, Book VII, Def.11](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookVII/bookVII.html): "A *prime number* is that which is measured by a unit alone." This means that **n** is prime iff there is no **k > 1** such that **n** is multiple of **k**. Thus, **7= 7 x 1** is prime and **2=2 x 1** is prime.

Comment: The *formal* definition must be: "**Prime(n)** iff for every **k**, for every **h** (if **n=kh** , then either **k=1** or **k=n**)".

Comment: Thus consider **n=2**; we have that: for every **k**, for every **h** (if **2=kh** , then either **k=1** or **k=2**) holds (not vacuously) and thus we can safely conclude with: **Prime(2)**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is 2 considered a prime number?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/50179/why-is-2-considered-a-prime-number)

Comment: A number p is prime if it has no factors other than 1 and itself.  Those factors can be anything else; they don't _have_ to be between 1 and p (with respect to primality).  If 13 were a factor of 2, 2 wouldn't be prime.  Although it's easy to show that if p has a factor other than 1 and p it must be between 1 and p;  you would still strictly need to actually do that easy work to show it.

Comment: @JeffUK

In the first question I did not at all convinced that the number is a prime number; in the second question, I was convinced that the number of two is a prime number, but its type was not clear.

Comment: What is the point of this distinction without a difference?  Mathematics (outside Intuitionism or constructivism, and they only in infinite cases) does not make the distinction between proof and vacuous truth -- consistency is proof, because the negation of negation is identity.  It is noted when it occurs in arguments because it sometimes points out that you are asserting mathematical convention over the objection of intuition.  It is still not part of the argument.  The product of an empty set of numbers is 'vaccuously' 1.  But it is still absolutely always 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One could consider 2 a “vacuous” prime number if one defines the word “vacuous” to refer to a natural number having the set of its possible divisors greater than 1 but less than that natural number as empty.  More simply for natural numbers, it would be the set of natural numbers greater than 1 and less than that natural number.  If the set is empty then call the natural number “vacuous”. Then 2 would be the only vacuous *prime* number in the set of natural numbers, but that is not a problem.

What is more troubling is that 2 would also be the *only* vacuous natural number even if one considered composite numbers.  No other natural number would be “vacuous” since every other natural number has a non-empty set of possible divisors that are less than the number and greater than 1.  This makes me wonder how useful the idea of “vacuous” is.  Is it only an idea that makes sense for 2?

Contrast the idea of “vacuous” with the idea of “even”.  The natural number 2 is also the only “even” prime number.  What makes “even” promising and potentially more useful than “vacuous” is that there are other even natural numbers.  The idea of “even” not only works with 2 although these other even natural numbers are composites.  The idea of “even” is useful beyond the number 2.

Although one could come up with a definition for a vacuous natural number, that it might apply only to the natural number 2 and not to any other natural number restricts its usefulness.

Comment: > This makes me wonder how useful the idea of “vacuous” is?

Given the definition of prime numbers, it can be said that it depends on the definition

Comment: @Achmed It itself may not be useful, but that doesn't mean it isn't worth considering.  Something useful, and perhaps surprising, may come out of considering even options that one ultimately doesn't use.

Comment: If we had a word for numbers divisible by 3, the fact 2 is the only even prime would stop sounding so surprising.

Comment: @Veedrac Good point about 3. It is really the unit 1 that needs to be handled separately to focus on the core idea of unique factorization.

Answer (score 3):

To disentangle the following issues:

1. *Relation between truth and counterexample*: A statement is true if and only if no counterexample exists. The term "potential" is superfluous.
2. *Tautology*: A tautology is a statement which is true independently from the truth-value of its components. Example: "X or not X" is true independently from the truth value of the variable X.
3. *Vacuous truth*: A statement which is true, because it refers to the empty set. Example: All kings of France in the 20th century had red hair.

The statement "2 is a prime number" is true because it satisfies the definition, see your question [Why is 2 considered a prime number?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/50179/why-is-2-considered-a-prime-number) 
The fact, that the number "2" satisfies the definition by trivial reason, has no relevance for the truth value of the statement.

"2 is a prime" is not a vacuous truth because primality of a given number is a statement about **all** integers: The proof shows that none pair of integers different from 1 and 2 satisfies the product relation.

Note: For any x, the non-existence of such integer factors is exactly the content of x being prime. The non-existence of these factors is not a vacuous truth.

Comment: There is an empty set between two and one.

Comment: @Achmed Yes. But first you have to prove that only numbers between 1 and 2 are candidates for the factorization. Why not 2= x*y with x,y >3? To exclude this case you need a rule how multiplication behaves with respect to ordering: Namely the rule x>2 and y>2 implies x*y>2.